# Sum of the series with Stirling numbers of the first kind.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, summation

Yesterday I worked on one problem in discrete math and in the process of decision I came across this series. Try to do it with generating functions, but there is no success for me.
So, what do you think about this sum? s(n - 1,k) - Stirling number of the first kind.
$$\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n - 2}\frac{s(n - 1,k)\cdot k\cdot2^k}{n!}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $(x)_n$ be the failing factorial i.e. :

$$(x)_n=x(x-1)...(x-n+1) $$

Then from the definition of the Stirling numbers of the first kind :

$$(x)_n=\sum_{k=0}^ns(n,k)x^k $$

Then :

$$\frac{d}{dx}(x)_n=\sum_{k=0}^ns(n,k)kx^{k-1} $$

Then, taking $x=2$ :

$$\frac{d}{dx}(x)_n(2)=\sum_{k=0}^ns(n,k)k2^{k-1}$$

So :

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}s(n,k)k2^k=2\sum_{k=0}^ns(n,k)k2^{k-1}-s(n,n-1)(n-1)2^{n-1}-s(n,n)n2^n$$

$$=2\frac{d}{dx}(x)_n(2)-\begin{pmatrix}n\\2\end{pmatrix}(n-1)2^{n-1}-n2^n $$

Now we want to compute $\frac{d}{dx}(x)_n(2)$, if $n=2$ then $(x)_2=x^2-x$ and then :

$$\frac{d}{dx}(x)_2(2)=3$$

if $n=3$ then $(x)_3=x(x-1)(x-2)$ then :

$$\frac{d}{dx}(x)_3=(x-1)(x-2)+x(x-2)+x(x-1)$$

Then, we see that it is easy to evaluate in $2$ all but one polynomials in the sum will be null hence :

$$\frac{d}{dx}(x)_3(2)=2$$

For $n\geq 3$ we will have (expand the derivative, evaluation in $2$ will kills all but one of the polynomials in the sum):

$$\frac{d}{dx}(x)_n(2)=2\times (-1)^{n-3}(n-3)!$$

Now this gives you a formula for your number.

Comment: What does it mean (x)(2)  
Are you computing a falling factorial in x = 2 ?

Comment: It's really strange to my task...
So my task was that: 
I must to insert n different digits from {1..n} in binary tree
So I made my own formula to compute a number of permutation, which need a k action. So P(n,k) = s(n - 1,k)*k*2^k

Comment: @openspace my notation is not very clear. I admit. I never evaluate a falling factorial $(x)_n$ in $2$ for the very reason (that you undoubtly remarked) that if $n\geq 2$ then $(x)_n(2)=0$. I evaluate the derivative of the falling factorial by $x$ in $x=2$ which (almost) gives you the number you want. I admit that the formula you get on the whole with my calcul is far from being beautiful. I did a mistake in my calcul (I will correct it) it is just before "now we want to compute..."

Comment: I thought about fact, that my task couldn't have < 0 actions. So, maybe I made mistake...

Comment: And your formula is work for s(n,k) not for s(n-1,k)